# How do you interpret this formula of a density function?

Tags: probability, statistics, density-function

I have the following formula:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxnWv.png
Y and Z are variables with density functions.
f_(Y=y)(z) what is that? the density of y given z? As far as i understand the right side is the joint density of y,z divided by density of y, i am mostly unsure about the left side. Tyvm in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It’s the conditional probability that $Z=z$ given $Y=y$. Hope this helps!

Comment: Tyvm for your help. definetely helpful. I thought it was something in that direction but i was not certain.